# Djongo+Mongo add expiration (auto-delete) to model objects

Tags: python, django, mongodb, djongo

Is there a simple way in Django to add an expiration date to documents via the model meta?

For example, in pymongo you can do something like this:

```
mongo_col.ensure_index("date", expireAfterSeconds=3*60)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best solution so far was to add the field in the model:

--- my_model.py ---

```
    ...
    objects = models.DjongoManager()
    ...
```

And then just somewhere in the code:

`MyModel.objects.mongo_create_index("created", expireAfterSeconds=60*60);`